# Adding a circle to a section title

Tags: sectioning, formatting, circles

I want a circle around a roman numeral *inside a section title*.

A command `\circled` is made from:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}   
...

%Circle around characters
\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(C.base)]\node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.5pt](C) {#1};\!
}
```

a solution I have from [the latex community forum](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=6301). It works very well surrounding a character with a circle. When I try to put this inside a `\subsection` command to add it to a section title, it actually works, but I get many errors.

**Result**:

[image]

**Warnings**:

[image]

What is wrong here? It works apparently, but can I fix the errors?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  Using `...` in the preamble is an error

Comment: Shouldn't `\circled` be `\protect`ed?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: Yes, it should ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\circled` is a fragile command this way (due to the `\tikz` etc content).

It must be `\protect`ed then. Or define it with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, as for example `\robustcircled`, which can be used without `\protect` then.

**As a general rule: Use robust commands as arguments to the `\section` etc. commands.**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}   

%Circle around characters
\newcommand*\circled[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(C.base)]\node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.5pt](C) {#1};
}


\DeclareRobustCommand*\robustcircled[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(C.base)]\node[color=blue,draw,circle,inner sep=0.5pt](C) {#1};
}


\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,...,5}{%
\section{\protect\circled{\x} The super theory on brontosaurs}
\foreach \y in {1,...,6}{%
\subsection{\robustcircled{\y} The theory of brontosaurs -- version \y}
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In what sense *fragile*? Does other packages interferre with this homemade command?

Comment: @Steeven: No, the command breaks into parts and confuses tex. A robust command does not break.

Comment: @Steeven To add a little to Christian's explanation: fragile commands break when used in moving arguments (such as the arguments for sectional unit commands or `\caption`, for example). For a comprehensive explanation, see the answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/3954.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks for that further explanation. I was unsure whether I should mention the moving arguments too...